# How to transpose Excel columns into a new range ignoring blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new at VBA and tried finding already existing solutions but none answered fully my requirements:
My initial list has holes (blanks) and I need to list the results as transposed without these blank fields
[image]

column A has files # and then 5 columns with prices but some are having only one price others 2 others 3 etc but never more than 3 prices. And these are varying from one month to another with hundred lines of it.

My first trials were no success as I couldn't find the totals expected.
My initial code was the following but it doesn't catch last 2 columns as there are blank fields in between:

```
Dim LR As Long, Rw As Long, Col As Long, LastCol As Long, CurRw As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B:B").Insert xlShiftToRight

For Rw = LR To 2 Step -1
    If Range("D" & Rw) <> "" Then
        LastCol = Cells(Rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Rows(Rw + 1).Resize(LastCol - 3).Insert xlShiftDown
        Range("A" & Rw).Resize(LastCol - 2) = Range("A" & Rw)
        Range("B" & Rw).Resize(LastCol - 2).Value = Range("C" & Rw).Resize(LastCol + 5).Value
        Range("C" & Rw).Resize(1, LastCol - 2).Copy
        Range("B" & Rw).Resize(LastCol - 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
        Range("C1").Resize(1, LastCol - 2).Copy
        Range("C" & Rw).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Else
        Range("C" & Rw).Copy Range("B" & Rw)
        Range("C1").Copy Range("C" & Rw)
    End If
Next Rw"
```

Thanks for your help. wishing this is now easier to understand and assist ;-)

Result to reach:
[image: RESULT TO REACH]

Comment: What were your first attempts>

Comment: cannot paste formula here

Comment: Turns table data into columnar data
'Adds titles in row1 as a new column of values

Comment: Ah, now it becomes much clearer, thanks. But I still didn't get what's going wrong and what do you mean by "*but it doesn't catch last 2 columns*". Can you also add an image of the actual result of your code so we can see what it actually does?

Comment: Yes if you run macro step by step you can figure out that it skips the $50 amounts for instance. And I'm unable to understand where is the instruction to make sure to take all columns in consideration (Last Col stop to first emtpy field for each line. no ?

Comment: Why are you checking column D `Range("D" & Rw) <> ""` if it is empty? I guess what you wanted is something like `If Range("C" & Rw) = "" Or WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C" & Rw & ":G" & Rw)) > 1 Then` but this is only a hint. With `WorksheetFunction.CountA` you figure out how many prices are in the range. This should help you a little but doesn't solve the whole issue. I recommend to turn on screen updating and going through the code step by step (F8) to see what each line does. Also read [VBA Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices).

Comment: Thanks a Lot Peh, this is exactly what I was missing ! Looks everything sorted now. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

using your image with file in A1, would be along these lines

```
Sub Example()

    Range("b2").Resize(1, 10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Copy
    Range("m2").Value = Range("b2").Resize(1, 10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Count
    Range("n2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

count will be in M and Transposed in N

[image]

Comment: Just to mention: This only works if all the values are constants and doesn't work if there are formulas used.

Comment: Great, and if I need the file a to be listed here 4 times in front of each line ? so instead of count I would like to see the file a in each of these 4 lines

Comment: Just basing it off the image shown, and assuming a pricing matrix.  As Peh suggests, it will need tweaking, it also only works for 1 row at the moment :)

Comment: Indeed and I have a list of 5000 rows for instance

Comment: @LAtropy Well this is not a "other people write the whole code for me" site. This site is good for answering a good asked detailed and specific question. But you should at least show some effort to solve your issue, because no one writes the whole code for you that you can just copy and paste. Try to write your code and then edit your question add your code and ask a specific question to your code e.g. where you got stuck, what errors you got and where etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula, like this `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$J$2,1,SMALL(IF($B$2:$J$2<>"",COLUMN($B$2:$J$2)-1),ROWS($L$1:L1))),"---")` filled down

[image]